# java constructor in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, inheritance

I have 2 subclasses: Staff, Student
they belong to superclass Person.

Here is the code(tasks) which is given by my teacher:

---

```
public class Person
{

   private String name;
   private int yearOfBirth;

   /**
    * Create a person with given name and age.
    */
   Person(String name, int yearOfBirth)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
   }
}
```

---

```
class Student extends Person
{

   private String SID;    // student ID number

   /**
    * Create a student with no parameters.
    */

   Student()
   {
    //task.
   }
}
```

---

```
public class Staff extends Person
{

   private String roomNumber;

   /**
    * Construct a staff member with field values and no pamaeters.
    */
   public Staff()
   {
    //task 
   }
}
```

I don't know what can I type in order to create an object without parameter.
It always appears an error like: constructor Person in class Person cannot be applied to given types; required: java.lang.String,int;

I have checked online that there are 2 ways to solve the problem:

1. add a default value in the superclass: `Person()//without parameter`.

   In the subclass Student:

```java
Student()
  {
  Person astudent = new Student() //I guess.
  }
```

2. add a super() in the subclass:

```java
Student()
 {
  super("xxx")//I guess.
 }
```

I don't know what to do. I an a starter in learning BlueJ.
Hope anyone can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since your superclass `Person` doesn't have a default constructor, in your subclasses (`Student` and `Staff`), you must call the superclass constructor as the first statement.

You should define your sub-class constructors like this:

```
Student() {
    super("a_string_value", an_int_value);// You have to pass String and int values to superclass
}
```

---

```
Staff() {
    super("a_string_value", an_int_value); // You have to pass String and int values to super class
}
```

Comment: Right, But why java compiler behave this way? When it is creating empty constructor when no provided, Why it isn't creating when having parameter?

Answer (score 3):

the first thing a constructor will do, is call the constructor (with same arguments) of the super class.
Person does not have a no-argument constructor, so, you must change your code in one of next two ways:

```
Student(String name, int yearOfBirth)
{
 //task.
}
```

or

```
Student()
{
super("", 0);
 //task.
}
```

and the same goes for Staff

Answer (score 3):

Add `super(NAME_IN_STRING_TYPE,YEAR_OF_BIRTH_IN_INT_TYPE);` as a first statement in your subclasse's constructor like

Student constructor

```
Student()
{
super("name", 1970); // String,int arguments passed
 //task.
}
```

Staff constructor

```
Staff()
{
super("name", 1970); // String,int arguments passed
 //task.
}
```

This is needed since there is no default no-arg constructor in the base class. You have to explicitly define a no-arg constructor in base class or you need to instruct the compiler to call the custom constructor of the base class.

Note : Compiler will not add default no-arg constructor in a class if it has a user defined constructor. It will add the default no-arg constructor only when there is no constructor defined in the class.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Student(String name, int yearOfBirth) {
   super(name, yearOfBirth);
   // task...
}
```

Reason: you dont have a default constructor at your superclass. So you have to call `super()` at the first position in your subclass constructor.

Answer (score 2):

To construct instance of `Student` you need to do actions neccesary to construct `Person` first. There is only one way to construct `Person` - two-arg constructor. That means you have to change `Student` like:

```
public Student() {
    super("someName", 1950); //first values came to my mind
}
```

Although you should be aware that `Student` should behave exactly like `Person` if treated as `Person`, i.e. have age and name. So actually I'd recommend to change `Student` constructor to include name and age there.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an object of child class (ie Staff and Student) without passing parameters then you can create an additional constructor without parameters in the parent class (ie Person class) as below.

```
public class Person
{

   private String name;
   private int yearOfBirth;

   /**
    * Create a person with given name and age.
    */
   Person(String name, int yearOfBirth)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
   }
   
   // additional constructor without parameter
   Person(){
      // add your code here
   }
}
```

now below code will work without any error.

```
Staff stf = new Staff();
Student std = new Student();
```

Answer (score 1):

for constructor no param you should have two constructors like

```
public class Student {
Student(String name , int dateOfBirth)
{
 super(name,dateOfBirth)
}

Student()
{
 //task.
}

}
```

also same for other class

Answer (score 1):

student should not extend person.
bcoz, if we create obj for student, person’s constructor will be called automatically.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).